# Remapped keys do not work with combinations

Tags: vim

I am trying remap `{` to `K` and `}` to `J`.

My `.vimrc` file looks like this:

```
nnoremap K {
nnoremap J }

onoremap K {
onoremap J }
```

It works for movement, but it fails when combined with operators like `d` and `c`. How can I make these mappings work with operator combinations?

Comment: The maps you've provided work well for me. Type `:map K` and `:map J` to verify your maps have not been overwritten.

Comment: As an aside, I would not recommend mapping neither `J` nor `K`. Their default functionality can be quite useful. Rather use `<leader>J` and `<leader>K`.

Comment: Do they work in combinations with other commands such as `d`? for example can you do `dJ` to delete to the next blank line?

Comment: Yes, this is what the `onoremaps` do. Placing the cursor at the beginning of a paragraph and typing `dJ` (in normal mode of course) deletes the paragraph.

Comment: please always post the output of `:verbose map KEY?` or at least verify it!